# Most pythonic way to stitch an array of images together

Tags: python, image, opencv, numpy

I have an array of images from an automated microscope program acquiring images from a 96 well plate (image below). Each image is named as:

`<Well name>_s<site number>.tif`

Each well of the 96 well plate is further subdivided into sites, the sites are arranged in an X by Y matrix, and the numbers are arranged line by line (image below).

[image: 96 well plate layout]

[image: Site layout]

For example, an image in the (10,9)th site of the top left well in the 96 well plate would be named
`A01_s90.tif`.

What is the most Pythonic way to stitch the images together? I am currently using OpenCV to load the images and calling `numpy.concatenate` in four `for` loops, but this seems very unwieldy.

Comment: Concatenating arrays inside `for` loops is very inefficient because it forces a copy of the data on each call. You would be better off accumulating your subarrays inside a `list` and concatenating them outside of the `for` loops, or initializing one big array the same size as your final image and writing the subarrays to it using slice indexing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like the code below? I'm assuming that it's the stitching that's the problem, not the translation between filenames and well/site indices.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img_ysize, img_xsize = 20, 20 # size of single image
my, mx = 10, 10 # x/y grid of sites per well
ny, nx = 8, 12 # x/y grid of wells per plate
wgap = 20 # pixels gap between wells
stitched_x, stitched_y = (wgap+mx*img_xsize)*nx, (wgap+my*img_ysize)*ny

img_stitched = np.zeros((stitched_y, stitched_x), dtype=np.uint8)

def add_img(mxi, myi, nxi, nyi, img):
    assert img.shape == (img_ysize, img_xsize)
    xi = nxi*(mx*img_xsize + wgap) + mxi*img_xsize
    yi = nyi*(my*img_ysize + wgap) + myi*img_ysize
    img_stitched[yi:yi+img_ysize,xi:xi+img_xsize] = img

for nxi in range(nx):
    for nyi in range(ny):
        for mxi in range(mx):
            for myi in range(my):
                # ... get image data
                img = np.random.randint(0,255) * np.ones((img_ysize, img_xsize), dtype=np.uint8)
                add_img(mxi, myi, nxi, nyi, img)

plt.imshow(img_stitched)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Comment: This algorithm was indeed much faster than the previous concatenate based one upon implementation, and was also much neater from a code perspective.

Answer (score 3):

Han-Kwang Nienhuys's answer doesn't do away with the four nested for loops, which bothered OP.

Here's a modified version of his answer with just one for loop:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import product

img_xsize, img_ysize = 20, 20 # size of single image
mx, my = 10, 10 # x/y grid of sites per well
nx, ny = 12, 8 # x/y grid of wells per plate
wgap = 20 # pixels gap between wells
stitched_x, stitched_y = (wgap+mx*img_xsize)*nx, (wgap+my*img_ysize)*ny

img_stitched = np.zeros((stitched_y, stitched_x), dtype=np.uint8)

def add_img(mxi, myi, nxi, nyi, img):
    assert img.shape == (img_ysize, img_xsize)
    xi = nxi*(mx*img_xsize + wgap) + mxi*img_xsize
    yi = nyi*(my*img_ysize + wgap) + myi*img_ysize
    img_stitched[yi:yi+img_ysize,xi:xi+img_xsize] = img

for nxi, nyi, mxi, myi in product(range(nx), range(ny), range(mx), range(my)):
    # ... get image data
    img = np.random.randint(0,255) * np.ones((img_ysize, img_xsize), dtype=np.uint8)
                add_img(mxi, myi, nxi, nyi, img)

plt.imshow(img_stitched)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show(block=False)
raw_input("Enter")
```